# Downsizing to almost embedded linux

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, puppylinux

I have a thin client machine with Puppy Linux on it and it works well.

I would like to make it fast something like embedded Linux.

All it needs to do is to run one Procesing sketch/app (java) in full screen.

Is there a easy (beginner) way to remove:

all apps,

unneeded drivers,

desktop env.(not sure if I need it),

and everything else that is not necessary for running that processing sketch.

Comment: How about approaching this from the other direction? Take the smallest leanest linux distro that you can find and add things until it works for your purpose?

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion !  I have tried couple of other small Linux dis. and most of them do not work on specific hardware!

Comment: Also with my limited knowledge it is very hard to do anything in such limited environment .

Comment: Please give a little bit of context why you want this and how the resulting system is to be used. This allows for giving better answers.